# Rollback to previous Version in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, devops

I have deployed a python code to azure DevOps from the git repository and my team committed some changes due to that we are facing some issue. How I can go back to the previous version?

Comment: What do you mean "deployed code to Azure DevOps"? You don't *deploy* code to Azure DevOps; it's a repository hosting platform.

Comment: If you have CI/CD pipeline setup you can easily deploy last successful build. Open Project>Pipeline>Release>Select you CD pipeline and select last successful build and you can file redeploy option their.

Comment: Pankaj Rawat, Thanks for Giving me a solution...its worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Pipeline->Release, there we can see all the releases, we can select whichever the version we need and can deploy